# Issue comparing datetime.now and EC2 image creation_date

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm working on a Lambda function to delete AMIs (images) older than a set number of days. I'm comparing datetime.now with the image Creation_date. I can see that these values are returned in different formats.

datetime.now format - 2019-11-15 20:34:53.057320+00:00
image creation_date format - 2010-10-16T21::31:46.000Z

When I test this I get the error "'>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'",

My code is below. I believe the issue is due to the different date formats.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

import boto3
import collections
import sys
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

region ='us-east-1'

aws_account_numbers = {"MassIT-Engineering-Sandbox":"xxxxxxxxx"}

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    delete_time = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) - timedelta(days=320)
    print (delete_time)
    
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', 'us-east-1')
    images = ec2.images.filter(Owners=["self"])
    
    for name, acctnum in aws_account_numbers.items():
        roleArn = "arn:aws:iam::%s:role/EOTSS-Snapshot-Cleanup-120days" % acctnum
        stsClient = boto3.client('sts')
        sts_response = stsClient.assume_role(RoleArn=roleArn,RoleSessionName='AssumeCrossAccountRole', DurationSeconds=1800)
        ec2 = boto3.resource(service_name='ec2',region_name=region,aws_access_key_id = sts_response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
                aws_secret_access_key = sts_response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'], aws_session_token = sts_response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])

        for Image in images:
                try:
                        if delete_time > image.creation_date:
                                Image.delete()
                                print('AMI with Id = {} is deleted '.format(image.image_id))
                           
                except ClientError as e:
                        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidSnapshot.InUse':
                                print("Snapshot in use")
                                continue
                        else:
                                print("Unexpected error: %s" % e)
                                continue
                        
        return 'Execution Complete'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the image.creation_date from string to datetime.

Here how it is done:

```
t = datetime.datetime.strptime(image.creation_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```